# Getting binary body from request NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I need to write a handler for all types of form. I check the work via postman. What I've just written works for all forms except binary.
[image]

As a result, I get the error

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    at rawParser (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/raw.js:81:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
```

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
const { raw } = express;
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({parameterLimit: 100000, limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.all('*',raw({type: '*/*'}), upload.array('files', 12), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.json({
    method: req.method,
    path: req.originalUrl,
    query: req.query,
    headers: JSON.stringify(req.headers),
    body: {
      fields: req.body,
      files: req.files
    },
  });
});


app.listen(port,(err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
});
```

how to properly get body from such binary form?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to send something bigger than 50MB but you have set request body limit to 50MB. Just try removing the limit and see if the Postman request works

Comment: @slebetman No, i send image 100kb and get this error. But i tried send txt 90byte and this working. I dont understate why(